# If f(x) is a m degree polynomial and there exist m+1 distinct numbers such that they all map to 0, then f(x) is the 0 polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

If f(x) is a m degree polynomial and there exist m+1 distinct numbers such that they all map to 0, then f(x) is the 0 polynomial.
This seems like common sense, but how does one formally prove this? I was a bit confused by the wording because if f(x) is the 0 polynomial then there everything gets map to 0 which is way more than m+1 elements. And also, shouldn't the 0 polynomial have negative infinity degree?

Comment: The statement is... poor. By definition, a degree $m$ polynomial cannot be the zero polynomial. Instead, it should say that if $f$ is a polynomial of degree *at most* $m$ (assuming your zero polynomial has degree; often it does not). As to the question: the magic words are Factor Theorem.

Comment: (The degree of the zero polynomial is a matter of convention; some people like to define it as $-\infty$; some people like to define it as $0$; some people like to leave it undefined, in essence saying that the zero polynomial does not have a degree at all. I’m in the latter camp. Whatever you choose, you end up having to write in exceptions to one or another theorem to account for your choice).

Comment: If you revise this question to supposing that $f$ has degree at most $m$, then you can use the fact that distinct roots correspond to distinct linear factors, i.e. if $f$ is $0$ at $a_1,a_2,...,a_{m+1}$ then $x$ is divisible by $x-a_1,...,x-a_{m+1}$. This implies that $x$ has degree $\geq m+1$ or it is the zero polynomial.